# upgrade weblogic server 12.1.2 . to 12.2.1.3

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm a newby with weblogic server. I want to do an upgrade of of weblogic servers but I don't know which steps I have to follow.

I know that we have to find matrice compatibility to prepare this upgrade, take a snapshot of the server before any upgrade.

I want to know which way is easier, steps to follow.

The architecture:
OHS as a webserver,
nodemanager OHS,
admin server weblogic,
nodemanager weblogic and instances.

Comment: reading the [ugrade doc](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WLUPG/intro.htm#WLUPG107) could be a good starting point.

Comment: i'm reading it but i want to know the starting point, i was searching for matrix compatibility .